# exit and error handling in golang

Tags: error-handling, go

I am new to Golang and I've seen it is very common to check for errors all the time.
I am trying to find a way to not have my code polluted with "if error { log... }" or "if error { exit }".
What do you think of a function like:

```
fun exitIfError(error err) {
  if error != nil {
    exit(1)
  }
}
```

That body of the function would be otherwise spread throughout the main function several times, but it would probably make less explicit where the program exits, any opinions?

Comment: Go is a very opinionated language, and explicit error propagation is one of its opinions. You *can* convert an error to an exit or panic, but that's only feasible in applications, not libraries. If you're not forced to use that language consider switching to a more productive language. E.g. Rust also supports Go-like explicitness but simplifies the `err = fallibleOperation(); if err != nil { return err }` pattern to `fallibleOperation()?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Go Proverbs - Rob Pike - Gopherfest - November 18, 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c)
>
> Don't just check errors, handle them gracefully.

---

A Go package may be used in a client program that supports tens of thousands of users concurrently. Just because you have a problem in one goroutine, don't crash everybody.